# How to debug request-promise which fail with ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, curl, request, debian, request-promise

I'm running Debian 6 with NodeJS6 and request-promise.
I'm using request-promise to deliver web hooks. Currently, we are delivering around 2+M web hooks each day.

Most of the time everything runs fine, but there are cases where the HTTP request simply isn't delivered.

This is my simple code:

```
requestPromise({ url: 'https://change-iot-request/do', auth: { user: "switch", pass: "my-password" }, method: "GET", timeout: 15000, rejectUnauthorized: false})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Sometimes the endpoint simply doesn't receive anything.
I've tried to run tshark to see if packages came through - nothing on any of the servers.

If I when it occurs run curl command with the same parameters the request DOES come through.

And if I restart the NodeJS it starts to deliver correctly again.

This is the error output:

```
{"name":"RequestError","message":"Error: ETIMEDOUT","cause":{"code":"ETIMEDOUT","connect":true},"error":{"code":"ETIMEDOUT","connect":true}
```

What to do?

Especially when curl does work so the connection should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can be a lot of causes, maybe it's not node fold at all
ETIMEDOUT means that your server do not get response for request

you can try set a timeout, something like

```
var rp = require('request-promise');


var reqPromise = rp({
    method: 'get',
    uri: 'http://localhost:8080/test-connection-length',
    timeout: 600000, // 10 min.
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
});
```

or install node-retry and your server will re-run automatically when it's needed

Comment: Seems process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 128; changes everything... Can that be it?

Comment: @MichaelNielsen maybe, I don't know how threading works in a deep level on node js

Comment: How can I apply node-retry to my example?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-retry or even https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-retry

Comment: Seems request-promise-retry is obsolete or has not been updated in a while. It says requires a peer of request-promise@^2.0.1 but none was installed, but I've got request-promise@^4.2.1. Trying to look at promise-retry.

Comment: I'm ginving you the correct answer, thank you. The promise-retry seems to work.